# Link lifetime of data to notebook cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I am looking for a way to attach some data to an arbitrary cell, with the following requirements:

- Given the `CellObject` for the cell, I can retrieve the data
- The data are not stored directly in the cell (i.e. I want to store huge amounts of data without having to push everything to the front-end)
- The data can be lost if the kernel is quit
- The data should be freed when the cell is removed/regenerated (i.e. the cell should be treated as the only way to access the data)
- This has to work for any existing cell (so I can't expect to be able to really modify it in some crazy way)

Some things I have considered, but couldn't make work:

- `TaggingRules`: This could work for an arbitrary cell, but would require me to store the data directly into the cell

  ```
  CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], {TaggingRules, "key"}] = 2;
  ```

  The `2` is not stored in the notebook, and modifying the attached data (i.e. the `2`) would require me to update the cell again.
- `` Language`ExpressionStore ``: I couldn't figure out how to use a `CellObject` as the "owner" of the data

  ```
  s = Language`NewExpressionStore["test"]
  (* Language`ExpressionStore["test"] *)

  s["put"[EvaluationCell[], "key", 2]]

  s["listTable"[]]
  (* {} *)
  ```

  As you can see, the store is always empty, even if the cell still exists
- `Temporary` variables: I tried to somehow store the data into a temporary variable and to store that into `TaggingRules`, but it seems cleanup of the variable does really work.

  ```
  Module[{a = 2},
   CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], {TaggingRules, "f"}] = Hold@a;
   ]
  ```

  Checking with `?a*`, you can see that the variable never seems to disappear.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Or is it somehow impossible, given that cells can in principle be "resurrected" by undoing the action deleting the cell?